# make font-size depend on div size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make font-size depend on div size (since the div is square-shaped, it doesn't matter whether it depends on height or width). Here's my code:

```js
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000,
   today = new Date();
   takeoff = new Date("05/28/2018"),
   remaining = Math.round(Math.abs((today.getTime() - takeoff.getTime()) / (oneDay)));


  var loop = new Date(today);
   mon = 'apr',
   adding = 0;

  


  for(var i=0; i<remaining; i++) {
   var elem = document.createElement("div");
   elem.className = "part";
   elem.id = 'p'+i;
   document.getElementById("days").appendChild(elem);
  }


  var parts = document.getElementsByClassName("part");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      parts[i].style.fontSize = (600/remaining) + 'px';
      parts[i].style.lineHeight = (500/remaining) + 'px';
  }

  while(loop <= takeoff) {
   if (loop.getMonth() == 3) {
    mon = 'apr';
   }
   else if (loop.getMonth() == 4) {
    mon = 'may';
   }

   parts[adding].textContent = (loop.getDate() + " " + mon);           

   var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
   adding += 1;
   loop = new Date(newDate);
  }



  for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
   parts[i].style.height = parts[i].style.width;
  }
```

```css
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }

  #days {
   position: absolute;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;

      table-layout: fixed;
      border-spacing: 1px;
  }

  .part {
      display: table-cell;
      background-color: #a9cce3;
      padding: 3px;

      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="days">
     
</div>
```

But it works a bit incorrectly. Plus all those fontSize calculation make the code look dirty, I guess. Could you please suggest a better solution?

Comment: [I wrote an obscure Javascript function for that.](https://liebdich.com/blogen) Search for **Responsive font size**. Demo — not — working more.

Comment: When you say it works incorrectly, can you give an example how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rem for font size unit to set responsive font size

```js
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000,
   today = new Date();
   takeoff = new Date("05/28/2018"),
   remaining = Math.round(Math.abs((today.getTime() - takeoff.getTime()) / (oneDay)));


  var loop = new Date(today);
   mon = 'apr',
   adding = 0;

  


  for(var i=0; i<remaining; i++) {
   var elem = document.createElement("div");
   elem.className = "part";
   elem.id = 'p'+i;
   document.getElementById("days").appendChild(elem);
  }


  var parts = document.getElementsByClassName("part");

  

  while(loop <= takeoff) {
   if (loop.getMonth() == 3) {
    mon = 'apr';
   }
   else if (loop.getMonth() == 4) {
    mon = 'may';
   }

   parts[adding].textContent = (loop.getDate() + " " + mon);           

   var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
   adding += 1;
   loop = new Date(newDate);
  }



  for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
   parts[i].style.height = parts[i].style.width;
  }
```

```css
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }

  #days {
   position: absolute;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;

      table-layout: fixed;
      border-spacing: 1px;
  }

  .part {
      display: table-cell;
      background-color: #a9cce3;
      padding: 3px;

      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 2px;
font-size:0.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<div id="days">
     
</div>
```